# help me design my login.jsp page

Tags: jsp, servlets

I want user to provide login + password to login to my webapp. If he fails some times captcha comes to action.

I wonder what can I do, to remove java code from it, and to make it more readable and firstly - safety? If I move my second 'captch'ed' form to different JSP, which would be called by servlet when needed - how can I force user to use it? how can I block data sent via 'normal' login.jsp then?

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="net.tanesha.recaptcha.ReCaptcha" %>
<%@ page import="net.tanesha.recaptcha.ReCaptchaFactory" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head> 
        <title>User Login JSP</title>
        <script lang="JavaScript">
            function trim(s) {
                return s.replace( /^\s*/, "" ).replace( /\s*$/, "" );
            }

            function validate() {
                if(trim(document.frmLogin.userName.value)=="") {
                    alert("Login empty");
                    document.frmLogin.userName.focus();
                    return false;
                }
                else if(trim(document.frmLogin.userPassword.value)=="") {
                    alert("password empty");
                    document.frmLogin.userPassword.focus();
                    return false;
                }
            } 

            function validate() {
                if(trim(document.frmLogin2.userName.value)=="") {
                    alert("Login empty");
                    document.frmLogin2.userName.focus();
                    return false;
                }
                else if(trim(document.frmLogin2.userPassword.value)=="") {
                    alert("password empty");
                    document.frmLogin2.userPassword.focus();
                    return false;
                }
            } 
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
            Object failCounter = session.getAttribute("failCounter");
            int fails = 0;
            if (failCounter != null) {
                fails = (Integer) failCounter;
            }
            if (fails < 3) {
        %>

        <form name="frmLogin" onSubmit="return validate();" action="validateLogin" method="post">
            User Name <input type="text" name="userName" /><br />
            Password <input type="password" name="userPassword" /><br />
            <input type="submit" name="sSubmit" value="Submit" />
        </form>

        <%} else {
        %>    

        <form  name="frmLogin2" onSubmit="return validate2();" action="validateCaptcha" method="post">
            User Name <input type="text" name="userName" /><br />
            Password <input type="password" name="userPassword" /><br />
            <%
                ReCaptcha c = ReCaptchaFactory.newReCaptcha(PUBLIC_KEY, PRIVATE_KEY, false);
                out.print(c.createRecaptchaHtml(null, null));
            %>
            <input type="submit" name="sSubmit2" value="submit" />
        </form>

        <%
            }
        %>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you have any choice in the matter, and you are currently learning server-side web technologies, I strongly urge you to consider something other than JSP, or indeed servlets. There are much, much, better technologies available these days.

Comment: @Marcin, in my case changing technology isn't an option. Its part of my Engineer's thesis :)

Comment: Then, my commiserations. Anyway, you've discovered one of the reasons why people use other technologies.

Comment: I don't know that I would consider leveraging a servlet changing technologies. Do you have a constraint that all your code be housed within the JSP? Servlets are Java standard architecture, not third party frameworks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I wonder what can I do, to remove java code from it, and to make it more readable and firstly - safety?*

Since a [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) is not an option, you have to resort to JSP includes. Add the following to top of your JSP:

```
<jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/loginAction.jsp" />
```

with

```
<%
    if ("GET".equals(request.getMethod())) {
        // Do here the job as you would in a normal servlet doGet() method.
        // You only don't need to call RequestDispatcher#forward().
    }
    else ("POST".equals(request.getMethod())) {
        // Do here the job as you would do in a normal servlet doPost() method.
        // You only don't need to call RequestDispatcher#forward().
    }
%>
```

Let the form finally just submit to self, i.e. remove `action`.

That bunch of JavaScript can also be refactored into a standalone `.js` file which you reference in `<head>`.

```
<script src="validator.js"></script>
```

Finally, you're repeating yourself in the form's code. Don't repeat yourself.

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="validate(this)">
    User Name <input type="text" name="username" /><br />
    Password <input type="password" name="password" /><br />
    <% if (request.getAttribute("captcha") != null) { %>
        Captcha <input type="text" name="captcha" /><br />
        <img src="<%= request.getAttribute("captcha") %>" /><br />
    <% } %>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Or if you have chance to use [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info), do

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="validate(this)">
    User Name <input type="text" name="username" /><br />
    Password <input type="password" name="password" /><br />
    <c:if test="${not empty captcha}">
        Captcha <input type="text" name="captcha" /><br />
        <img src="${captcha}" /><br />
    </c:if>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Further I fail to understand the safety point. Please be more specific. Note that your validation won't work whenever the enduser disables JS. Check [our servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) for a server side validation example.

---

> *If I move my second 'captch'ed' form to different JSP, which would be called by servlet when needed - how can I force user to use it? how can I block data sent via 'normal' login.jsp then?*

Just check the session attribute if the user needs to enter a captcha.

Comment: You can see my answer - my code after refactoring using your ideas :) Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @BalusC i managed to refactor my page to this:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>User Login JSP</title>
        <script type="text/javascript"  src="javascript/formDataValidator.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="frmLogin" onSubmit="return validate();" action="validateCaptcha" method="post">
            User Name <input type="text" name="userName" /><br />
            Password <input type="password" name="userPassword" /><br />

            <c:if test="${ (sessionScope.failCounter != null) && (sessionScope.failCounter > 2 ) }"> 
                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.recaptcha.net/challenge?k=6Ld9k8cSAAAAAB6jx0I_wu4f0n2zUL7QqYOC5JgM"></script>
            </c:if>

            <input type="submit" name="sSubmit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

With external JS file.

Using scriptlet for captchha wasn't needed, so i replaced it with this what was created inside `out.print` which was allways the same `String =` script call.

So IMO it was worth doing this refacor :)